# Detect GOPATH from project Makefile

Tags: go, makefile

If `GOPATH` is not set, compilation for `go` programs is impossible. But many `go` projects are built using Makefiles, because `go` also miss capabilities to extract `git` revision, set version etc. So it should be possible to detect GOPATH from Makefile automatically.

Suppose I set my GOPATH manually one time for `go get -d`:

```
go get -d github.com/zyedidia/micro/cmd/micro
```

Now if I open another session, `cd` into `github.com/zyedidia/micro/cmd/micro` and do `make build`, the build fails:

```
...
cmd/micro/micro.go:20:2: cannot find package "layeh.com/gopher-luar" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/layeh.com/gopher-luar (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

So, if `GOPATH` is not set, how can I set it from the `Makefile` and make sure that there is `go` environment at this point?

This doesn't work:

```
GOPATH ?= ../../../..
```

**UPDATE**: The following code works, but it doesn't detect that parent directory contains `src`, `bin` and `pkg` dirs.

```
export GOPATH ?= $(abspath $(dir ../../../../..))
```

`export` is needed to transform `make` variable into environment variable, `?=` sets `make` variable only of it is not set, `abspath` and `dir` are described here:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
# detect GOPATH if not set
ifndef $(GOPATH)
    $(info GOPATH is not set, autodetecting..)
    TESTPATH := $(dir $(abspath ../../..))
    DIRS := bin pkg src
    # create a ; separated line of tests and pass it to shell
    MISSING_DIRS := $(shell $(foreach entry,$(DIRS),test -d "$(TESTPATH)$(entry)" || echo "$(entry)";))
    ifeq ($(MISSING_DIRS),)
        $(info Found GOPATH: $(TESTPATH))
        export GOPATH := $(TESTPATH)
    else
        $(info ..missing dirs "$(MISSING_DIRS)" in "$(TESTDIR)")
        $(info GOPATH autodetection failed)
    endif
endif
```

What I've learned:

- variables are defines in a separate block
- tabs are not allowed in the block that defines variables
- `echo` doesn't work in this block, need to use `$(info)`

Comment: I have a generic Go makefile [here](https://gist.github.com/aprice/7471d17d2dbab7c5d4ea634c4cb5f678) which covers finding the package path by assuming the makefile is in the root of the project. In a makefile I assume Go is installed and GOROOT/GOPATH are set correctly.

Comment: My use case is that GOPATH is not set at all and compilation fails. I don't need to find out what package path is.

Answer (score 11):

I met the same problem, here is my solution:

```
ifndef $(GOPATH)
    GOPATH=$(shell go env GOPATH)
    export GOPATH
endif
```